# Webkit scrollbar issue in mobile?

Tags: css, css-selectors, webkit, scrollbar

I am trying to have a custom scrollbar and using the webkit css to make changes to it; but it is not working as expected when we inspect of go to smaller screen it is showing a default scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color: #ccc;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: #ffcc35;
}

body {
scrollbar-width: thin;
scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
}

:empty {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: FYI Does not work on Firefox see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

Comment: yes, I tested but the things is -webkit is not working for -webkit support browser on mobile

Comment: Maybe provide some images of what's happening, and your browser version